# set a node selected by default in dijit.Tree

Tags: dojo, tree, selection

I'm using dijit.Tree, I need to set a node selected by default (after the data loaded) ? I have tried to search it in dojo documentation, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can select a tree node programmatically by setting the tree's 'path' property.  A path is an array of string item id’s, starting with the root node and going down to the leaf node which you want selected.

example:

```
tree.set('path', ['parent', 'child', 'grandchild'])
```

In this example grandchild is the node you want selected.

Documentation and examples for this can be found on the Dojo website [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tree-examples.html#expanding-and-selecting-tree-nodes-programmatically)